# Can not format date as per requirement using PHP

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I am trying to format the existing date using PHP but it didn't work as  expected. My code is below:

```
$edate="03/12/2016 12:01:43 PM";
$date=date('m/d/Y H:i:s A',strtotime($edate));
echo $date.'<br/>';
```

Here I need to display the month first, like this format: `mm/dd/yyyy` but with my code its giving me the following result:

> 03/12/2016 12:01:43 PM

whereas I should get a result like this:

> 12/03/2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `/` with `-` for the input date:

```
$edate="2/12/2016 12:01:43 PM";
$_edate = str_replace('/', '-', $edate);
$date=date('m/d/Y H:i:s A',strtotime($_edate));
echo $date.'<br/>';
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), try this:

```
date("m/d/Y", strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $edate)));
```

Comment: I have already mentioned the month should come first. Please check my post.

Answer (score 0):

See http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

```
 $edate="03/12/2016 12:01:43 PM";   
 $date = new DateTime($edate);
 echo $date->format('m/d/Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `DateTime` and then you can format date in any format.

First you have to convert to your date format using `createFromFormat()` and then use `format()` to format in any date format

Just try this

```
<?php
    $edate="03/12/2016 12:01:43 PM";
    try {

    echo DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i:s A', $edate)->format('m/d/Y');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "error";
        exit(1);
    }
?>
```